# Best way to use GetxController in nested widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

In my Flutter app I use GetxController as a viewModel for every view:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

import 'track_activity_view_model.dart';

// Main widget of the view
class TrackActivityView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetBuilder<TrackActivityViewModel>(
        init: TrackActivityViewModel(),
        builder: (viewModel) {
          return SafeArea(
              child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Registra un\'attività')),
            body: viewModel.serviceEnabled
                ? AskPermissionWidget()
                : TrackingWidget(viewModel),
          ));
        });
  }
}

class AskPermissionWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetBuilder<TrackActivityViewModel>(
        init: TrackActivityViewModel(),
        builder: (viewModel) {
          // Some code that use viewModel
          return Container();
        });
  }
}

class TrackingWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final TrackActivityViewModel viewModel;

  TrackingWidget(this.viewModel);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Some code that use viewModel    
    return Container();
  }
}
```

When I write some nested widget, I'm wondering if is it better

1. Call the controller ex-novo (AskPermissionWidget)

or

2. Pass the controller as a parameter (TrackingWidget)

Are there any differences?

Thank-you very much.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In *GetX* you need not to struggle anymore with **dependency injection** (this is the title of what you asked). Even it is one of the main benefits of *GetX* over other packages.

You need to do following steps to get the things around:

1. Just create (and bind) your ViewModel(s) (or better named *Controller*s) using :

   **a.** `Get.put` or `Get.lazyPut` methods used in constructor or `build` method of the **top** widget

   **b.**  or using `init` parameter of `GetBuilder` in the **top** widget to construct a new controller

   **c.**  or using [Bindings](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/blob/master/documentation/en_US/dependency_management.md#bindings-class) for any page to define the *Controller*s related to that page.
2. Find your *Controller* in the child widgets or anywhere else using `myViewModel = Get.find<MyViewModel>()`. You need not any more to initialize it in the child or pass it within constructors. It always find the right *Controller* for you. Or if you want it to be used in `GetBuilder` you could use the `GetBuilder` in the child without any `init` paramter or anything else. Just write this in your child widget :

```
    return GetBuilder<TrackActivityViewModel>(
        builder: (viewModel) {
          // Some code that use viewModel
          return Container();
        });
```

and the GetBuilder itself finds the right *Controller* for you. No need to pass it anything else (after you ensured that the controller is initialized in a top widget or it is a `permanent` controller which will not be removed from the memory).

Isn't it simple ?! As I mentioned, this is the major advantage of *GetX* over the other state management packages.

**note :** If you want multiple instances of a single `Controller` class, you would be able to pass a unique [`tag` parameter](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/blob/master/documentation/en_US/dependency_management.md#getput) in `Get.put` or `Get.lazyPut` or in the `GetBuilder` or `GetX` widget to uniquely define the `Controller` and then in the child widgets or anywhere you want to find it use that unique `tag` to identify which one do you want.

**Summary :** **GetX always finds the right Controller.**